# Nginx rewrite rule: make directory accessible from one address only

Tags: nginx, webserver, url-rewriting, modx

I use Nginx as a web server and I want to deny access to a particular directory from certain domains. Or in other words, make that path/directory only accessible from one domain or IP address.

Example:

> http://domain.com/manager/     => Redirects to 404 page
>
> http://www.domain.com/manager/ => Redirects to 404 page
>
> `http://10.10.10.10/manager/`             => allows access

Finally, to make this a complete solution, I'd like to force an https connection when accessing to this particular path.

Following my previous example:

> `http://10.10.10.10/manager/`          => Rewrites to https

Comment: does `domain.com` resolves to `10.10.10.10`?

Comment: No, it's just an example for the sake of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
location / {
deny all;
allow [ip];
}
```

And restart your services.

More : http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html

Comment: This rule applies to the whole site instead of the `/manager` path only.

Answer (score 0):

To address the force https (Assuming you already have a nginx that listens to port 443)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  10.10.10.10;

    rewrite ^(.*) https://10.10.10.10$1 permanent;
}
```

To address the redirect to 404, you can consider using the following in your main config that listens for server "domain.com"

```
location ~ ^/manager {
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: This solution rewrites all traffic to https. That wasn't part of the request.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     domain.com;

    # Redirect path to secure connection
    location ^~ /manager {
      rewrite ^/(.*) https://domain.com$1 permanent;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443;

    location ^~ /manager {
      allow 10.10.10.10;
      deny all;

      error_page 403 =404 /404.html;  
    }
}
```